# Gradle selects wrong version from maven-metadata

Tags: gradle, dependencies, artifactory

Having this *maven-metadata.xml*:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata modelVersion="1.1.0">
  <groupId>com.project</groupId>
  <artifactId>project-common-lib</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <versioning>
    <snapshot>
      <timestamp>20230509.122340</timestamp>
      <buildNumber>6</buildNumber>
    </snapshot>
    <lastUpdated>20230509122340</lastUpdated>
    <snapshotVersions>
      <snapshotVersion>
        <classifier>plain</classifier>
        <extension>jar</extension>
        <value>0.1.6-20230509.122121-5</value>
        <updated>20230509122121</updated>
      </snapshotVersion>
      <snapshotVersion>
        <classifier>sources</classifier>
        <extension>jar</extension>
        <value>0.1.6-20230509.122121-5</value>
        <updated>20230509122121</updated>
      </snapshotVersion>
      <snapshotVersion>
        <extension>pom</extension>
        <value>0.1.6-20230509.122340-6</value>
        <updated>20230509122340</updated>
      </snapshotVersion>
      <snapshotVersion>
        <extension>module</extension>
        <value>0.1.6-20230509.122340-6</value>
        <updated>20230509122340</updated>
      </snapshotVersion>
    </snapshotVersions>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

*(Artifactory as repo)*

I would assume that as plain jar the version
`com.project:project-common-lib:0.1.6-SNAPSHOT:20230509.122340-5` 
is resolved. But Gradle gives as dependency insight this:

```
com.project:project-common-lib:0.1.6-SNAPSHOT:20230509.122340-6 (selected by rule)
  Variant apiElements:
    | Attribute Name                     | Provided     | Requested    |
    |------------------------------------|--------------|--------------|
    | org.gradle.status                  | integration  |              |
    | org.gradle.category                | library      | library      |
    | org.gradle.dependency.bundling     | external     | external     |
    | org.gradle.jvm.environment         | standard-jvm | standard-jvm |
    | org.gradle.jvm.version             | 17           | 17           |
    | org.gradle.libraryelements         | jar          | classes      |
    | org.gradle.usage                   | java-api     | java-api     |
    | org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type | jvm          | jvm          |
```

Which does not exist, cause only the "-5"-version exists apparently according to the metadata. In artifactory we have non-unique setting for snapshots. So where's the exact problem?